# grep search for a string with a hyphen in the middle

Tags: string, grep

I am looking for files that would contain the string `abc-def` in a folder.

I am using `grep -l -r abc-def *`, but I am not sure if that is the right way (no files were found when this command was used, but perhaps it simply means that no file contains the string). I have also tried `grep -l -r 'abc-def' *` (found files, but when I manually looked for the string they were not there, only the individual parts of the string, i.e. abc and def). Since the pattern does not start with a hyphen -e would not work here.

**What would be the proper way to grep search for a string with a hyphen in the middle?**

Comment: Since a hyphen is not a special character to shell or grep (except inside a character class) then it simply means that no file contains the string.

Comment: @Neil: ok, thanks a lot (I just needed to make sure) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `grep -r abc-def` first to see which lines match. `grep -r abc-def *` and `grep -r 'abc-def' *` should really yield the same result.

`fgrep` (f is for 'fixed string`) is not necessary here.

Comment: just to make this answer more complete, refer to Neil's comment above: hyphen is not a special character so it shouldn't matter if it's in the middle of the string

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
fgrep -r -l 'abc-def' .
```